# How to prevent "You have already authorized this app" message on Facebook connect in WP8.1?

Tags: windows, facebook, facebook-graph-api, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I'm learning to integrate facebook login in WP8.1. My problem is that I **need** facebook to ask me for my credentials every time I press the connect button but it does not do that, it remembers the last log in and prompts "You have already authorized my_app_name". How do I go around this? Is there anyway I can prevent facebook to remember the last login?
I've followed [THIS](http://bsubramanyamraju.blogspot.in/2014/12/windowsphone-store-81-facebook.html) tutorial, just fyi

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This is by design on the Facebook side of things. When your app gets authorized, the information is associated with the user on the Facebook side. The user has to unauthorized the app in order to get this prompt again.

Comment: You can force the user to enter their password again before proceeding, using the `auth_type` parameter with value `reauthenticate ` for the login dialog. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/reauthentication

Comment: AbdulwahabSuleiman-MSFT, I know this is by design but I wanted to look for a workaround to this.  I found the solution and I posted it as an answer here.

CBroe , I tried doing that but it did not log me out completely, it just prompted me for the password again while retaining the email id of the last logged in facebook user.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out the solution to this. When the user taps on the connect to facebook button, I silently call the logout uri using `WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateSilentlyAsync`. This does not open the UI thread and logs out the previously logged in user before opening the facebook connect dialog.

So essentially every time a user tries to connect my application to facebook, it logs out the previous logged in user before presenting the connect dialog.

Answer (score 1):

The web authentication broker must have enabled `single-sign-on` that prevents asking credentials the next time it is invoked. This behavior is obtained when a callback URI is not specified in the authentication method of `WebAuthenticationBroker`.

`WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync` has 2 overloads - one accepting callback URI and the other not. You can use the one with callback URI and provide the default redirect URL of Facebook (https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html)

Refer [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh750287.aspx) for details.

Also as *Abdulwahab Suleiman - MSFT* mentioned in the comment, once Facebook has authorized your app - you have to get it unauthorized for the permissions prompt to be seen again. After authorization you can see your app listed in Facebook (Settings -> apps). You can either remove it from there or revoke the Facebook permission through code.