# Facebook SDK C# Windows Phone 8.1 (Non Silverlight)

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-8.1

I've got a trouble with Facebook OAuth authentication in my Windows Phone 8.1 app and
I've done everything like this tutorial: **[blog](http://bsubramanyamraju.blogspot.com/2014/12/windowsphone-store-81-facebook.html)** 
It works fine, but there is one very annoying thing: Every time when I tap on Login button I got a popup "**You have already authorized this app**".
I spent on this trouble a lot of time so please help me. 
Thank you in advance.

### It's still actually.

Comment: Is there anyone who knows how to avoid this popup?

Comment: Does this help? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32078145/how-to-prevent-you-have-already-authorized-this-app-message-on-facebook-connec/32086220

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution to this. When the user taps on the connect to facebook Login button, I silently call the logout uri using 
**WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateSilentlyAsync**. This does not open the UI thread and logs out the previously logged in user before opening the facebook connect dialog.

So essentially every time a user tries to connect my application to facebook, it logs out the previous logged in user before presenting the connect dialog.I figured out the solution to this. When the user taps on the connect to facebook button, I silently call the logout uri using **WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateSilentlyAsync**. This does not open the UI thread and logs out the previously logged in user before opening the facebook connect dialog.

Comment: I saw this suggest on techsupport. But it isn't refers to Facebook authentication in tutorial which I pointed. I will be glad if you could explain how to do this.

Comment: Have you get access token from facebook ? if yes then I have a solution for that

Comment: Yes I have Access Token